# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

How is it possible to get duplicate entry error from this **auto scaffold** from .net identity code:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser {  UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

Produces this stacktrace:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry '3ab1a765-c575-4a50-ba42-6d282ccb24a6' for key 'PRIMARY' ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry '3ab1a765-c575-4a50-ba42-6d282ccb24a6' for key 'PRIMARY'
>      at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.TryAsyncContinuation(Task`1 task) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 1252
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 43
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 81
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ReadFirstResultSetAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 307
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(MySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, ResultSetProtocol resultSetProtocol, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 292
>      at MySqlConnector.Core.TextCommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(String commandText, MySqlParameterCollection parameterCollection, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\TextCommandExecutor.cs:line 37
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.CreateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Chuchubi.Data.MultiTenant.TenantUserStore.CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Dropbox\Code\chuchubi-backend\Chuchubi.Data\MultiTenant\TenantUserStore.cs:line 30
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user, String password)
>      at Chuchubi.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel.OnPostAsync(String returnUrl) in C:\Users\Dropbox\Code\chuchubi-backend\Chuchubi\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Register.cshtml.cs:line 71
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert[T](Object taskAsObject)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at SaasKit.Multitenancy.Internal.TenantResolutionMiddleware`1.Invoke(HttpContext context, ITenantResolver`1 tenantResolver)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]

This was from auto generated code from visual studio.

EDIT:

MySql version details:

```
'immediate_server_version', '999999'
'innodb_version', '8.0.16'
'original_server_version', '999999'
'protocol_version', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'tls_version', 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2'
'version', '8.0.16'
'version_comment', 'MySQL Community Server - GPL'
'version_compile_machine', 'x86_64'
'version_compile_os', 'Win64'
'version_compile_zlib', '1.2.11'
```

my csproj:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SaasKit.Multitenancy" Version="1.1.4" />
```

This is done on a empty database, after the error there is no user being inserted in the database!

Comment: It's strange, is there any record with `3ab1a765-c575-4a50-ba42-6d282ccb24a6` in the database? Share us the `Startup.cs`. Is there any other operation on `ApplicationUser`. If you create a new empty database, will this issue happen?

Comment: Hi @TaoZhou oh yea i forgot to mention, i'm doing this on a empty database, and no user is being added!

Comment: If so, it seems to be related with your code, is there any demo project to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I'll try to make one later! @TaoZhou i'll tag you when i have a link

Comment: How you defined Identity tables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok attempting to replicated this in a clean project i managed to figure it out.
So the application is multi-tenant, each identity user has a one on one relation with a tenant.

Using SaasKit i was caching the database model Tenant into memory, while creating a new user like so:

```
IdentityUser.Tenant = cachedTenant;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Entityframework sees the Tenant as a new tenant (not being tracked), therefor causing the duplicate message.

So the duplicate message was actually for the new tenant.

Fix by caching a 'view model' instead of the database model.